# Converting Ext4 Simple/Dynamic drive back to Basic/Partition

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems, dynamic-disk

So basically i was trying to add a 5th partition and in that process I've converted my whole disk to a dynamic drive, which contains both `NTFS` and `EXT4` with Linux on dual boot. Now the problem is it seems like i can't convert `EXT4` volume back to basic, but i'am able to convert `NTFS` volumes, which will result in Unallocating the `EXT4` volume.

1. So is there any software or a way to convert the dynamic disk back to basic disk including the `EXT4` partitions?

Extra Information:

1. Windows `Diskpart` shows the `EXT4` drive as `RAW`, Other disk management software's like AOMEI Partition Assistant show it as `UNKNOWN`, whereas the disk properties from `my computer` show it as `EXT4`

---

### Attempt-1

Following the link provided by @harrymc.

These are the partition on disk:
[image]
executing the `sfdisk --change-id /dev/sda 4 7` i converted the 4th partition to `NTFS`.
[image]
As you can see that my `Drive D` and `Drive F`, `NTFS & EXT4` are shown in a single partition `/dev/sda3` which is not true. Also my other partition `/dev/sda1` is nearly `1MB`.

So following the rest of the guide i converted them to ext4 & ntfs but when i started my windows os it showed the devices like this:
[image]
It converted the devices but the problem here is `sfdisk` cant differ b/w `partition 1` & `partition 2` and now it allocated both of them in a single drive.Where my `EXT4` drive is of `100GB` and `NTFS` partition is of `99.5GB`.

So the method failed and I've went back to revert changes and covert it back to dynamic disk and now i am back in the same place.

Comment: Try the article [Dynamic to Basic](https://abhishek27.wordpress.com/dynamic-to-basic/) for a method using the Linux utility of `sfdisk`. This might not work if any partition had extensions (most likely not by your description). Always take full backups before modifying partitions.

Comment: @harrymc check, I've updated the post.

Comment: Could you also add a screenshot of `sfdisk -l` before the change?

Comment: I may have an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have found an article for Windows 7:
[Convert a Dynamic Disk to a Basic Disk](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html).
This article describes doing the conversion without data loss,
using an old and free version of Partition Wizard 4.2 Free
(Partition Wizard is currently version 12, but only the
paid version can do this conversion).

I went as far as running the program and verifying that it starts up correctly
in Windows 10. I have (for obvious reasons) not dared to try actually converting
my disk between Basic and Dynamic.

The article lists this procedure:

- Download
  [Partition_Wizard_4.2_free.zip](https://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/395240d1484151587-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk-partition_wizard_4.2_free.zip)
  (also available [boot ISO](http://www.softsea.com/download/Partition-Wizard-Bootable-CD.html))
- Unzip and run `PWIZ.exe`
- Right-click on the dynamic disk and select "Convert Dynamic Disk to Basic Disk"
- Click OK
- Click the Apply icon and then Yes
- Reboot.

[image]

Always take a full backup before any disk or partition work.

---

**User experience as reported by the poster:**

In spite of Partition Wizard 4.2 not analyzing correctly the Linux partition,
the conversion to Basic was successful as regarding the disk,
with no data loss.

The Linux partition was preserved in content, but was marked as unallocated
in the partition table. To mark it again as ext2/3/4 needed changing
its id from `0` to `83` using a command such as:

```
 sfdisk --change-id /dev/sda 3 83
```

Finally `easybcd` was used to add the Linux partition to the bootloader and
it booted successfully.

Comment: i've tried that before.. i says you ext4 drive will be unallocated. that's the main issue here.

Comment: even though it says it will be unallocated. https://prnt.sc/smo91k. so i converted the drive to basic and it created 2 `unallocated` partitions.https://prnt.sc/smo9h6 One of which was my ext4 partition. So i though i should go back to `sfdisk` and change the `FileSystem` Type and i saw that id for unallocated filesys was `0`. https://prnt.sc/smoacs. Then i changed the id from `0` to `83` which is for `ext2/3/4`. https://prnt.sc/smoas4.Now windows disk manager showed this: https://prnt.sc/smob3o.Then i used `easybcd` to add my linux drive to bootloader and voila it booted successfully

Comment: please add the above information so that i can accept your answer. thanks

Comment: Glad the problem is now fixed. This post might be very useful to others. I did as you requested, but feel free to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1554502/edit) my answer and I'll ensure that it is done.

Comment: Thanks, you've been a great help.

Comment: You have also helped a lot in making this work out correctly.